# How to give equal spacing between individual images in a straight line in css?

Tags: html, css, image

I have screenshot as shown below which I have to replicate in HTML/CSS.

[image]

At this moment, I am able to replicate this in [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ksL6btfr/1/embedded/result/).

**In the fiddle, I am not able to give fair amount of spacing between individual images**.

In the **fiddle**, I have a feeling, there is a problem in the following CSS code:

```
.et_pb_row {
    position: relative;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 1080px;
    margin: auto;
}
```

**Problem Statement:**

As stated above, in the fiddle I am not able to **give equal amount of spacing between individual images**.

I am wondering what changes I should do in the fiddle so that I am able to give fair amount of spacing between individual images.

Comment: It seems that your fiddle doesn't reproduce the problem. Can you include a [working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to help demonstrate? Also, how do you define "fair"?

Comment: There is a login on the fiddle. Space between images can be done with img {padding-right:10px;}

Comment: @Heinz Schilling I am editing my question. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: This is a good case for grid. I updated your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zke9wrnd/1/

Comment: @showdev I have updated the fiddle in the question.

Comment: @HeinzSchilling I have updated the fiddle in the question.

Comment: @KaiQing I have updated the fiddle in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the browsers you need to support, you can use flexbox for that.
So if you have the following html:

```
<div class="container">
  <img src="" />
  <img src="" />
  <img src="" />
  <img src="" />
</div>
```

Then writes the following css:

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

See [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content) for more example.

Comment: Can you update it in the fiddle ? I tried but somehow I am not able to get equal amount of spacing between the images.

Comment: Your fiddle is full of useless code, please clean it and I'll have a look, but basically .et_pb_code_inner {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
} should be enough.